# gio mount works differently over vnc and working directly on the host

Tags: networking, mount, samba, vnc, gvfs

I need to mount a samba share on a linux machine using the `gvfs`. I have a script that reads $USERNAME and $PASSWORD and passes to `gio` as

```
echo -e "$USERNAME\nglobal\n$PASSWORD\n" | gio mount smb://<server_name>/<share_name>
```

I use vnc to connect remotely to this linux machine, and also work directly sometimes on it, but the behaviour of `gio mount` highly differs.

Over vnc, the location is mounted very quickly and always under `/run/user/666/gvfs/`.
But when I work physically with the linux machine, the same script is super slow to mount the smb share which is mounted at `~/.gvfs`.

For reference, my `~/.vnc/xstartup` contains

```
#!/bin/sh


[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
vncconfig -iconic &
gnome-session --session=ubuntu &
```

Is there a way to make this mounting location behaviour more predictable since the mount location will be further used by another application? Also any suggestions to make the mounting happen quicker would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What desktop sessions are you using in the local versus VNC case? Does your `~/.vnc/xstartup` file modify any `XDG-` variables?

Comment: @steeldriver I have added the contents of `~/.vnc/xstartup` in the original question now.